# Access NSCache across view controllers in a tab view controller

Tags: swift

I want to access NSCache from more than one place in my APP, as I'm using it to cache images from an API endpoint.

For example table view 4 and viewcontroller 6 in the diagram below use the same images, so I do not want to download them twice.

[image]

Candidate solutions:

1. Singleton

   ```
   class Cache {  

       private static var sharedCache: NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>?        
       static public func getCache () -> NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject> {

           if sharedCache == nil {
               self.sharedCache = NSCache()
           }
           return sharedCache!
       } 
   }
   ```

Seems to work fine, but "Singletons are bad" so...

2. Store the cache in TabViewController

This will tightly couple the views to the view controller so...

3. Store in the AppDelegate somehow. But isn't this the same as 1? So...
4. Use dependency injection. But we're in a tab view controller, so isn't this the same as 2?

I'm not sure the right strategy here, so am asking whether there is another method that can be used here.

**What I've done** Created an App with an example using a NSCache, and explored a singleton solution. Ive tried to use dependency injection but think that it doesn't make sense. I've looked at Stack overflow and documentation, but for this specific circumstance I have found no potential solutoins.

**What I've given** A minimal example, with a diagram and tested solution that I'm dissatisfied with.

**What is not helpful** are answers that say NSCache is incorrect, or to use libraries. I'm trying to use NSCache for my own learning, this is not homework and I want to solve this specific instance of this problem in this App structure.

**What the question is** How to avoid using a singleton in this instance, view controllers in a tab view controller.

Comment: why "singletons are bad"?

Comment: The antipattern argument - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/88/how-to-implement-singletons-in-swift-the-smart-way - https://medium.com/@johnsundell/avoiding-singletons-in-swift-5b8412153f9b  - pros and cons https://medium.freecodecamp.org/singleton-design-pattern-pros-and-cons-e10f98e23d63 - but rather the issue is what is the alternative?

Comment: If your cache sole purpose is to store the image in cache, then you should consider using SDWebImage framework, which is widely known and used for caching images

Comment: What is not helpful are answers that say NSCache is incorrect, or to use libraries. I'm trying to use NSCache for my own learning, this is not homework and I want to solve this specific instance of this problem in this App structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up. Singletons are not inherantly bad. They can make your code hard to test and they do act as dependancy magnets.

Singletons are good for classes that are tools e.g `NSFileManager` aka `FileManger`, i.e something that does not carry state or data around.

A good alternative is dependancy injection but with view controllers and storyboards it can be hard and feel very boilerplate. You end up passing everything down the line in `prepareForSegue`.

One possible method is to declare a `protocol` that describes a cache like interface.

```
protocol CacheProtocol: class {
    func doCacheThing()
}

class Cache: CacheProtocol {
    func doCacheThing() {
        //
    }
}
```

Then declare a `protocol` that all things that wish to use this cache can use.

```
protocol CacheConsumer: class {
    var cache: CacheProtocol? { get set }
    func injectCache(to object: AnyObject)
}

extension CacheConsumer {
    func injectCache(to object: AnyObject) {
        if let consumer = object as? CacheConsumer {
            consumer.cache = cache
        }
    }
}
```

Finally create a concrete instance of this cache at the top level.

```
/// Top most controller
class RootLevelViewController: UIViewController, CacheConsumer {
    var cache: CacheProtocol? = Cache()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        injectCache(to: segue.destination)
    }

}
```

You could pass the cache down the line in `prepareForSegue`.

Or you can use subtle sub-classing to create conformance.

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, CacheConsumer {
    var cache: CacheProtocol?
}
```

Or you can use delegate methods to get the cache object broadcast downhill.

```
extension RootLevelViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        injectCache(to: viewController)
    }
}
```

You now have a system where any `CacheConsumer` can use the cache and pass it downhill to any other object.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the coordinator pattern you can save the cache in the coordinator for your navigation flow and access it from there/init with the cache. It also works nicely since when the navigation flow is removed the cache is also removed.

```
final class SomeCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
    var rootViewController: UINavigationController
    var myCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
    
    override init() {
        self.rootViewController = UINavigationController()
        super.init()
    }
    
    func start() {
        let vc = VC1(cache: myCache)
        vc.coordinator = self
        rootViewController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
        parentCoordinator?.rootViewController.present(rootViewController, animated: true)
    }
    
    func goToVC2() {
        let vc = VC2(cache: myCache)
        vc.coordinator = self
        rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func goToVC3() {
        let vc = VC3(cache: myCache)
        vc.coordinator = self
        rootViewController.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func goToVC4() {
        let vc = VC4(cache: myCache)
        vc.coordinator = self
        rootViewController.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("✅ Deinit SomeCoordinator")
    }
    
}
```